# Make lsoda terminate once state variable reacjes a threshold value

Tags: r, differential-equations

As a toy example, consider the differential equation, dx / dt = p x

```
  ODE = function(t, X, p){ list( p*X ) }
```

One can solve this using `lsoda` from package `deSolve` with no problem.

```
  times = seq(0, 20, by=.1)
  out = lsoda( y = 1, times, ODE, p = 2 )
```

However, I'd like `lsoda` to stop computing after a threshold value has been reached, say `xMax = 1e5`. I coudn't seem to find this option in the documentation. There is an option for `events` which looks promising for possibly implementing something like this.

Answer (score 1):

In the deSolve documentation for lsoda you can also find the `rootfunc` parameter which can be used to trigger an event at root locations.

See example 3 in https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/deSolve/versions/1.10-9/topics/events for an example that seems very close to your test case.